# Use variable X to find maximum value of Y

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, convergence

Let's say I have inputs 'A' and 'B' for my function, which outputs 'C'. For each value of A, I would like to find what value of B results in the maximum value of C; I would then like to record values B and C. Is there a function that can perform this action? Perhaps something which depends on convergence mechanisms?

*in case you found this through one of the non-python related tags I applied, please make note that I am using python 3.x

Comment: What is the range of possible values for B?

Comment: With provided info, brute-force is the only way. Evaluate the function for every possible `B`, record the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define function [image: 1] to take parameters (A,B)[image: 2]  and return a value C[image: 3]. We can optimize this with Python by doing

```
from scipy import optimize

f = lambda a,b: ... # your_code_which_returns_C
optimal_vals = np.zeros((2, len(list_of_all_A_values)))
for i, a in enumerate(list_of_all_A_values) # assuming some list is defined above
    b_opt, c_opt, *rest = optimize.fmin(lambda b: -f(a,b), 0)
    optimal_vals[:,i] = np.array([b_opt, c_opt])
```

This takes advantage of scipy's [`fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) function, which relies on the convergence of the downhill simplex algorithm. For this reason, it's crucial to not forget the minus sign on [image: 1].